# How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\sin^{2n+1}x=0$, for $x \in (0, \pi /2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> How to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\sin^{2n+1}x=0$, for $x \in (0, \pi /2)$?

My answer is simply infinity. But the answer given is $0$. How is it possible ?

Comment: why do you think it is infinity?

Comment: look at the variable, the limit is for $x$ variable not $n$

Comment: Question and title are two different things :(

Comment: Sorry it will be n to infinity.

Comment: Is that a power or an iterated $\sin$?  It makes a big difference in the answer.

Comment: I do not understand,

Comment: Exponents attached to functions could mean two different things.  Common interpretations for $f^2(x)$ might be $(f(x))^2$ or $f(f(x))$.  The first is a power, the second is iterated.

Comment: What is iterated sin?

Comment: What is $x$?  If $x=0$ then certainly the limit is 0, but if $x=\pi/2$ the limit is certainly $\infty$.

Comment: x \in (0, \pi /2), it is given

Comment: Then it is just zero.

Comment: How it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in(0,\pi/2)$, $|\sin x|<1$.

**Exercise**:  Let $r$ be such that $0<r<1$. Show that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} nr^{2n+1}=0
$$

Hint: Note that for $0<r<1$,
$
\ln r<0
$
and 
$$
nr^{2n+1}=\frac{n}{e^{-(2n+1)\ln r}}.
$$
Now apply L'Hopital rule.